# Bash - read specific line from a file with all sorts of data and store as a variable

Tags: bash

I have looked for an answer to what seems like a simple question, but I feel as though all these questions (below) only briefly touch on the matter and/or over-complicate the solution.

[Read a file and split each line into two variables with bash program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793051/read-a-file-and-split-each-line-into-two-variables-with-bash-program)

[Bash read from file and store to variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270289/bash-read-from-file-and-store-to-variables)

[Need to assign the contents of a text file to a variable in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116748/need-to-assign-the-contents-of-a-text-file-to-a-variable-in-a-bash-script)

What I want to do is read specific lines from a file (titled 'input'), store them variables and then use them.

For example, in this code, every 9th line after a certain point contains a filename that I want to store as a variable for later use. How can I do that?

```
steps=49

for((i=1;i<=${steps};i++)); do

       ...

        g=$((9 * $i + 28)) #In.omega filename
```

`

For the bigger picture, I basically need to print a specific line (line 9) from the file whose name is specified in the *g*th line of the file named "input"

```
        sed '1,39p;d' data > temp
        sed "9,9p;d" [filename specified in line g of input] >> temp
        sed '41,$p;d' data >> temp

        mv temp data
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to assign the **49th** line of the `$FILE` file to the `$ARG` variable, you can do:

```
$ ARG=`cat $FILE | head -49 | tail -1`
```

Answer (score 0):

To get line 9 of the file named in the gth line of the file named input:

```
sed -n 9p "$(sed -n ${g}p input)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arg=$(cat sample.txt | sed -n '2p')
```

where `arg` is variable and `sample.txt` is file and `2` is line number